# Does order of loops matter for speed in R

Tags: r

I have a problem where I want to run a simulation study where the simulation depends on two variables `x` and `y`.  `x` and `y` are vectors of potential values that I want to evaluate (so different combinations) in my simulation study.  Furthermore, for each combination of `x` and `y` I want multiple replicates (since there is a stochastic term in there and each run of `x` and `y` will vary).

To give an example of what I am dealing with I have the following simplified example:

```
x = 1:10
y = 11:20

iterations = 2000
iter = 1

solution = array(NA,c(length(x),3,iterations))
for(i in x){
    for(j in y){
        for(k in 1:iterations){ 
            z = rnorm(3) + c(i,j,1) 
            solution[i,,k] = z
        }
    }
}
```

However in my actual problem, the code that get evaluated inside the for loop is much less trivial to evaluate. However, the structure of my inputs are the same as well as the output.

So what I would like to know, say using the above example, is it most efficient to set up the loops in that order or would it be better to let `k in 1:iterations` be the outermost loop and try to use some sort of `outer()` command within that 1 loop since I will be evaluating the function (`z` in this example) over the grid `x` and `y`?

Also, I am very open to a completely different set-up and design.  At the end of the day I want to be able to obtain a solution that is based on `x` and `y` and averaged over all the iterations, i.e., `apply(solution, c(1,2),mean)`

---

## Edit:

As was suggested to me, here is the actual code that I am using.

```
library(survival)

iter = 2000
n = 120
base = 2
hr = 0.5
m.x = 3
m.y = m.x/hr

ANS = NULL
for (vecX in c(0.3, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7)){
out = NULL

    for (vecY in c(0, 0.05, 0.1, 0.15, 0.2, 0.25, 0.3, 0.4, 0.5, 0.6, 0.7, 0.8, 0.9, 0.95)){
        m.x.p = m.x/vecX
        m.y.p = m.y/vecX
        m.x.n = m.x
        m.y.n = m.y
        
        n.t = round(n*base/(base+1))
        n.c = n - n.t
        
        for (ii in 1:iter){
            n.t.p = rbinom(1, n.t, vecY)
            n.t.n = n.t - n.t.p
            n.c.p = rbinom(1, n.c, vecY)
            n.c.n = n.c - n.c.p
            
            S = c(rexp(n.t.p, log(2)/m.y.p), rexp(n.t.n, log(2)/m.y.n), rexp(n.c.p, log(2)/m.x.p), rexp(n.c.n, log(2)/m.x.n))
            
            data1 = data.frame(Group = c(rep("T", n.t), rep("C", n.c)), dx = c(rep("P", n.t.p), rep("N", n.t.n), rep("P", n.c.p), rep("N", n.c.n)), S)
            
            fit = survfit(Surv(data1$S)~data1$Group)
            coxfit = coxph(Surv(data1$S)~data1$Group)
            
            HR = exp(coxfit$coefficients)
            p.val=summary(coxfit)$logtest["pvalue"]
            
            out = rbind(out, c(vecX, vecY, n.t.p, n.t.n, n.c.p, n.c.n, HR, p.val))
        }
        
    }
    colnames(out) = c("vecX", "vecY", "n.t.p", "n.t.n", "n.c.p", "n.c.n", "HR", "p.val")
    
    ans = as.data.frame(out)
ANS = rbind(ANS, ans)

}
```

Comment: I guess that it's really dependent on what you have inside the loop and whether you can vectorize it. In your example you could remove entirely the `k` loop by `z <- rnorm(3*iterations) + c(i,j,1);solution[i,,] <- z` gaining a lot of CPU time; similarly you could remove the other loops. I don't think that the order could make that much of a difference, while vectorization (if possible) surely will make a big difference.

Comment: @nicola the example above was completely made up. It was more so illustrative of the structure I have and the inputs and outputs.

Comment: Yes, I got that the example is made up. My point was that you have to try to vectorize. In my experience, there are a ton of circumstances in which one tries to save some time by using `lapply` instead of `sapply` or inverting loops where a vectorization was available and the programmer didn't realize it. This kind of optimizations are often negligible compared to the huge gain you may have if you succeed to vectorize. So, if you really want to optimize, try to rethink your code in such a way you can vectorize. If you can't, don't waste time to think about loop order.

Comment: @nicole, is it appropiate to post my actual code here for people to critique?  I didn't want to get flagged for basically posting "here is my code, please make it faster"

Comment: @Symbolix I'll update my question with my actual code.

Comment: @Symbolix I updated the code.

Comment: @Symbolix, sorry you can disregard the original example and focus only on my actual code

Comment: Shouldn't `nrow(ANS) == length(X) * length(Y) * iter`? Maybe you should set `out = NULL` after the first loop or am I missing something?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, I believe that in theory it should make a difference (see example below).

R uses column-major ordering like Fortran (and unlike C), so to minimize cache misses you'd want to be traversing down columns. So for filling a matrix, the optimal approach is the one where the outer loop has our column index.

And for n-dimensional arrays, you'd want to bear this in mind, too. In the case that `n = 3`, I guess this would mean having the layer be the outermost loop, then the column, then the row. I could be mistaken here, though.

I ran this quick example with `5000` by `5000` matrices. And we are seeing a difference of about 50 seconds, with `fill_matrix2()` being faster.

```
    n <- 5000
    A <- matrix(NA, n, n)
    B <- matrix(NA, n, n)

    fill_matrix1 <- function(X, val) {
        for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
            for (j in 1:ncol(X)) {
                X[i, j] <- val
            }
        }
        return(X)
    }

    fill_matrix2 <- function(X, val) {
        for (j in 1:ncol(X)) {
            for (i in 1:nrow(X)) {
                X[i, j] <- val
            }
        }
        return(X)
    }

    system.time(fill_matrix1(A, 0))
    system.time(fill_matrix2(B, 0))
```

Comment: For smaller "n", it seems that the timings do not differ between the two functions that much and for larger I can't get consistent behavior. Perhaps it's because of the difference of the `[<-` _function_ being called in each iteration in R than the respective operator (`*(x + i)`) in, e.g., C? As an example, calling the `[<-` function once and passing precomputed indices seems to -indeed- be slower when accessing rowwise. E.g. `n = 5e3; x = matrix(0, n, n); ij = c(t(row(x) + (col(x) - 1L) * nrow(x))); ji = seq_along(x); microbenchmark::microbenchmark({ x[ij] = 1 }, { x[ji] = 1 }, times = 25)`

Answer (score 4):

The order of the loops is practically irrelevant here. If you profile your code (see `help("Rprof")`) you'll see that the CPU time is spent in functions like `survfit` and `coxph`. And of course in growing `out`, which you should avoid. Pre-allocate `out` to its final size and fill it instead of growing it.

Comment: Sure, I agree that I should preallocate the sizes.  Is there anything else I can do to optimize the code to run faster?

Comment: As I indicated: Your first step should be profiling your code.